# Entity Framework Core detect changes to the Database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core

I'd like to call a function every time the database has any kind of changes.
How can I see if the database was updated and call a function at that same moment?

Comment: Have version of database variable that can be checked.

Comment: What does the function do? If the function is database related, then I'd suggest using `triggers` to accomplish this. What kind of application is running which needs to check for changes?

Comment: The function doesn't really mater I believe, I want to be able to trigger any kind of function but for this project I want to call a function to update some google contacts. I'd hoped that there is an event I can listen to built into ef but I didn't find one.

Comment: You need to give more details of what exactly you want, "*any* kind of changes" is pretty vague.

Comment: What database are you using? SqlServer, Oracle, MySql, something else?

Comment: In SqlServer you can use [SqlDependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1). [Detecting Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency). You can find ways to apply this in conjunction with EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the *EntityFramework Core* you can *override* the `SaveChanges()` method in `DbContext` file and call your function like this.

```cs
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    // call your function before changes 
    return base.SaveChanges();
    // call your function after changes 
}
```

And when you add any change in `DataBase` and call `SaveChanges()` method your functions run automatically.

You can get all changes in **EF** like this

```cs
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var changedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList();
    // call your function before changes 
    return base.SaveChanges();
    // call your function after changes 
}
```

Comment: But how to detect a change made by another application that also has access to the same database? How to notify the first application about the changes made by the second one? Assume that the used database is SQL server database.